# how would you change the character controller height in unity using code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: unity]

i tried googling this bs but couldnt find out how to do it

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController-height.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the Unity Scripting Reference, you can directly access and set the height property on the CharacterController class.

Start by gaining a reference to your CharacterController in your script
This can be done in two ways:

Start by defining a CharacterController variable in your script. You can either expose the variable in the Unity editor by using [SerializeField] or you can find the component by using GetComponent.

```cs
[SerializeField] private CharacterController controller;
```

or

```cs
private CharacterController controller;

void Start(){
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}
```

Once you have access to your CharacterController component, you can access the height property on it in your code. Here is an example on how you could do this to make a simple crouch mechanic

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        //Set height to 2 at the start of the game
        controller.height = 2.0f;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)){
            //Set the height to 1.5 if the left shift key is pressed
            controller.height = 1.5f;
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift)){
            //Set the height to 2.0 when the user releases shift
            controller.height = 2.0f;
        }

    }
}
```

For future reference, the Unity Documentation is a great resource for figuring out what properties and functions are available on components.
You can find the Unity scripting documentation [HERE](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/index.html).